# Why do I sing better after sport?

Tags: vocal-cords

I noticed that after a good amount of swimming, my vocal chords feel a lot more 'free', so hitting higher notes is less of a struggle. I also noticed that I'm able to achieve a more natural vibrato when singing post-swimming for the next hour or so.

What is it about the sport (or sports in general perhaps?) that cause this? I'd like to know so then I can be more self aware of when my vocal chords are relaxed versus tight.

Comment: The euphoria of exercising may make you feel good and relaxed.